# Crystal Reports "the ) is missing"

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm trying to run a report that has already been created and works. But when I try to run an error pops up with the 'Formula Workshop' screen and it says "the ) is missing". This is the formula displayed:

```
IF NumericText({?ASOFDATE}) THEN 

   "[" + ToText(pwFormatDate ToNumber({?ASOFDATE}))) + "]"

ELSE  

   "[ ]"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try that

```
IF NumericText({?ASOFDATE}) THEN

"[" + ToText(pwFormatDate ToNumber({?ASOFDATE})) + "]"

ELSE

"[ ]"
```

You put one extra parenthesis in formula

Answer (score 0):

Actually I think he left one out...

```
IF NumericText({?ASOFDATE}) THEN 

   "[" + ToText(pwFormatDate(ToNumber({?ASOFDATE}))) + "]"

ELSE  

   "[ ]"
```